# javafx menu items+change scene

Tags: javafx, menuitem

Всем хорошего дня. Есть задача, имеется окно, в scene есть меню вида MenuBar ->Menu->items->MenuItem
Далее в конроллерах перехожу с главной сцены, планировал что при переходе на определённый пункт меню, открывается новая сцена. Реализовать это через экшеневент как:

```
  Scene newScene = ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene();
        Stage newStage = (Stage) newScene.getWindow();
        newScene.getWindow().setWidth(600);
        newScene.getWindow().setHeight(600);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/scenes/ViewDeck_Scene.fxml"));
        Scene viewScene = new Scene(root);
        newStage.setScene(viewScene);
        newStage.show();
        viewScene.getRoot().requestFocus();
```

Но это увы не работает, как выяснилось меню айтемы не являются нодами. Прошу пояснить как тогда решить данный вопрос.

Comment: и как следствие:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Node
 at controllers.MainSceneController.ViewDeckClicked(MainSceneController.java:15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос, создав fx:id у MenuBar. -> теперь есть поле в контроллере, а через поле получил Stage.
Scene newScene = menuBar.getScene();
Stage newStage = (Stage) newScene.getWindow(); итд.